# Are there any classifications of death

Tags: vedas, bhagavad-gita, death, manu-smriti, agni-purana

I wish to know if death has classifications and what type of death is the best amongst those classifications

Comment: You mean like death by suicide, or by accident, or natural calamities, or battle field, or by disease, or old age etc?

Answer (score 1):

> दवौ संमतविह मृत्यु दुरापौ यद् ब्रह्मसंधारणाया जितासु:।
>   कलेवरं
> योगरतो विजह्याद्य यदग्रणी र्वीरशयेs निवृत: ॥33॥
>
> dvau sammatāv iha mṛtyū durāpau  yad brahma-sandhāraṇayā jitāsuḥ
> kalevaraṁ yoga-rato vijahyād  yad agraṇīr vīra-śaye ’nivṛttaḥ
>
> **Meaning** - There are two ways to meet a glorious death, and both are very rare. One is to die after performing mystic yoga, especially
> bhakti-yoga, by which one can control the mind and living force and
> die absorbed in thought of the Supreme Personality of Godhead. **The
> second is to die on the battlefield, leading the army and never
> showing one’s back. These two kinds of death are recommended in the
> śāstra as glorious.**

Even Shivapurana says the same thing.

And this  martyrism concept  is also clearly stated  in [**Shiva Mahapurana**](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-iii/chapter-21/topic-1)

- Uman samhita chapter 21 - shloka 25 – Page 83

> यस्तु शस्त्रमनुत्सुज्य म्रियते वाहिनीमुखे |
>  संमुखो वर्तते शूर: स
> स्वर्गान्न निवर्तते ||२४||
>
> One who dies in battleground , holding a weapon , such a warrior never
> returns from the heaven.

For a kshatriya, the best death is dying in battlefield.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06026.htm

> Slain, thou wilt attain to heaven; or victorious, thou wilt enjoy the Earth.

That is the reason why Duryodhana went to heaven despite his sins.

As mentioned in [Mahabharta, Book 18: Svargarohanika Parva: Section 1](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m18/m18001.htm) that Duryodhana went to heaven because he sacrificed his life in war.

> "Narada, smiling, told him, ‘It should not be so, O king of kings. While residing in Heaven, all enmities cease. O mighty-armed Yudhishthira, do not say so about king Duryodhana. Hear my words. Here is king Duryodhana. He is worshipped with the gods by those righteous men and those foremost of kings who are now denizens of Heaven. **By causing his body to be poured as a libation on the fire of battle, he has obtained the end that consists in attainment of the region for heroes. You and your brothers, who were veritable gods on Earth, were always persecuted by this one. Yet through his observance of Kshatriya practices he has attained to this region**. This lord of Earth was not terrified in a situation fraught with terror.